# How to handle a renewCredentialsForAccount error 100?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios9

I had a user who, on renewal request, got this message:

> Server refused renewal request with error code: 100

As a patch I'm just sending them to the FB SDK and having it do a Safari login/auth, but I wonder if I should know anything else about handling this?

Answer (score 0):

I have been experiencing the same issue with iOS9 Social Framework on iOS 9.

When the FB OAuth token has expired the ACAccountStore renewCredentialsForAccount always fails with renewStatusFailure (== 2) and with error:

> Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=1 "Server refused renewal request
>   with error code: 100" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Server refused
>   renewal request with error code: 100

The code was previously working on iOS 6, 7 and 8 but now the renew always seems to fail after the OAuth token has expired.

EDIT: It seems that this occurs when you develop App with same app bundle id (From iOS app perspective) but you use different Facebook AppID (sandboxed vs. live FB app) for production vs test/development builds. If I remove the app totally between build the issue seems to disappear. The problem seams to disappear also if I toggle the Facebook 'Allow these apps to use your account' toggle off+on under Settings Facebook

PS: Sorry for originally posting this as a answer and not comment, but due to SO's commenting reputation requirements I was unable to add this originally as a comment